# Simple Products with Custom Options in Grouped Products Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-options, products-management, grouped-products

I hope someone can help or knows of an extension that adds the functionality I require.

I have multiple simple products that each have their own custom options.

I then need to add these simple products to a bundled product. Magento out of the box only allows simple products without custom options to be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to allow custom options on bundle products by using the following code (it does edit some core files and there are a few paid extensions that achieve similar functionality):

Edit for file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Observer.php, namely just comment some code out as follows:

```
/*
        if ($product->getPriceType() == '0' && !$product->getOptionsReadonly()) {
            $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
            if ($customOptions = $product->getProductOptions()) {
                foreach (array_keys($customOptions) as $key) {
                    $customOptions[$key]['is_delete'] = 1;
                }
                $product->setProductOptions($customOptions);
            }
        }
*/
```

To get rid of “Bundle with dynamic pricing cannot include custom defined options. Options will not be saved.” message you should hack app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options.phtml template:

```
//show error message
/*
if ($('price_type')) {
    if ($('price_type').value == '0' && $('dynamic-price-warrning')) {
        $('dynamic-price-warrning').show();
    }
}
*/
```

I found this in the following thread on Magento's forums: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14910/P15/#t208213

I then required defaults to be set for the custom option on bundle products (and other products that used listed options) and used this extension to implement the functionality: https://github.com/magebuzz/Magebuzz_Customoption

Answer (score 0):

No need to go through all this trouble.

In order for the **simple product with custom option** to appear in the **Bundle Items** of your **bundle product**, the **options** of the **simple product** must *not* be set as required.

Set "**is required**" to "**no**" to all the options in your simple product and refresh filter in you bundle options.

However, this only puts the item in the group.  It does NOT automatically que the customer for any relevant custom option information such as size, color, etc.  So although it technically DOES allow it to be put in the group with this cheat, it very much defeats the need for those optional choices the seller will ultimately require to fulfill the order.

http://inchoo.net/magento/simple-product-custom-options-in-grouped-product/

[image]